# Need Algorithm for finding Highest match when comparing a list of strings

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a function that is importing columns from an excel sheet which I am then putting the column names into a list.

I have a list of 'System Columns' that the imported columns will eventually be mapped with.

The user will later have the ability to map these columns to any of the system columns, but I would like to make this process easier by intelligently trying to match the imported column name with the system column name that is closest to it.

For example

After importing their columns, I might have the following list of imported columns:

```
List<string> importedColumnNames = importService.ResolveColumnNames();

Console.WriteLine(importedColumnNames[0]); //Prints 'Security_ID'
Console.WriteLine(importedColumnNames[1]); //Prints 'User_ID'
Console.WriteLine(importedColumnNames[2]); //Prints 'Date'
```

**NOTE**The code for writing to the console is just to show some of the sample imported columns names.

Additionally, the code for the system column names might be the following:

```
List<string> systemColumnNames = GetSystemColumnNames();

Console.WriteLine(systemColumnNames[0]); //Prints 'Security Identifier' or 'Security ID'
Console.WriteLine(systemColumnNames[1]); //Prints 'User' or 'User Identifier'
Console.WriteLine(systemColumnNames[2]); //Prints 'Item Date' or 'Datetime'
```

Once these are imported, I would like to be able to find a way to match the importedColumnNames with a closest match system column name value.

```
Dictionary<string,string> matchedImportedColumns = MatchService.Match(importedColumnNames,systemColumnNames);

foreach(var item in matchedImportedColumns)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Imported Value '{0}' was matched to System Value '{1}',item.Key,item.Value);
}
```

This would hopefully print something like the following:

```
Imported Value 'Security ID' was matched to System Value 'Security Identifier'
Imported Value 'User ID' was matched to System Value 'User'
Imported Value 'Date' was matched to System Value 'Item Date'
```

One more note, I would expect that a question for this would be whether or not to make it case sensitive. I was hoping that could be something I could do at runtime by just passing in a boolean flag of whether to match using case sensitivity or not.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Does anybody care to enlighten me why this was down voted?

Answer (score 1):

I guess for your case the easiest thing to do (as in, best without busting out machine learning) would be to split them into words (on spaces and underscores, possibly on lower-to-upper-case transitions), downcase them, find the size of the set intersection between the query and each candidate, and return the candidate with the largest intersection. You could improve it by doing common substitutions that you observed, like "ID" -> "Identifier" (on both query and candidate set).

If you need to make an injective set-to-set match, then you need to do some dynamic programming to find the best non-conflicting set of matches, rather than just going sequentially and mapping the best to each.